# Escape forward slashes in bash script argument for sed replacement

Tags: bash, sed

I want to take a bash script param with forward slash like this `my_server/my_repo/my_image` and pass them into a `sed` function that does a replace on the string and rewrites for a different file.

I'm able to do this by escaping the forward slashes when setting the string, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

IMAGE_NAME="my_server\/my_repo\/my_image"
CURRENT_VERSION="1.0.0"
TARGET_VERSION="1.0.1"
TARGET_FILE="./my_deployment.yaml"

sed -i "s/$IMAGE_NAME:$CURRENT_VERSION/$IMAGE_NAME:TARGET_VERSION/" "$TARGET_FILE"
```

That's great, but when I pass the same string, escaped or unescaped, I can't get it to work. I'm pretty sure it is because the variable `$IMAGE_NAME` is unescaping the `/` while in the `sed` command, which completely throws off `sed` when doing the replacement.

I've tried various combindations escaping the argument and unescaping:

```
> ./myscript.sh my_server/my_repo/my_image
> ./myscript.sh my_server\/my_repo\/my_image
```

Tranforming argument when assigning it to `$IMAGE_NAME` and other varios combindations.

```
> IMAGE_NAME=$1
> IMAGE_NAME="$1"
> IMAGE_NAME=`echo $1 | sed 's/\//\\\//g'`
```

I'm sure it is something to do with how bash does strings and escaping but I can't figure how.

So, How do I get the string that is passed like this as an argument:

```
my_server/my_repo/my_image
```

Output this when being called from a variable:

```
my_server\/my_repo\/my_image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to protect the backslashes from the shell on the command line either by using quotes OR double them up.

```
myscript.sh 
'my_server\/my_repo\/my_image'
..... Or
myscript.sh my_server\\/my_repo\\/my_image
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent a few hours on this.... thank you so much!